# JS Runs sections of code inside a if statement when conditions are not met

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have this section of code that every 10 seconds it checks if the player has enough Xp to level up if they do it will add 1 to there level, double the neededXp and rest there Xp to 0.

but for some reason every 10 seconds it doubles needed Xp even when i don't have enough Xp it doesn't do any of the other things though. Also level up does work. (if i can get enough XP quick enough before it doubles its way to a large number)

```
window.setInterval(
function levelup() {
if (Xp >= neededXP)
    level = level + 1;
    neededXP = neededXP * 2;
    Xp = 0;
    document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level
    document.getElementById("neededXP").innerHTML = neededXP
               document.getElementById("Xp").innerHTML = Xp
               }, 10000);
```

Comment: `console.log(Xp >= neededXP, Xp, neededXP)` and stop guessing

Comment: It looks like your missing the block `{}` for the `if` clause.

Comment: OH... i knew it would be something stupid

Comment: Thanks I'm not that good at programming I'm only 14 and this is my second project. Thanks

Comment: Bugs like this are why it is good to get into the habit of always using a block with `if`, `else`, `for`, etc even if you only have a single line inside the block. If you add a second line and forget to add the block it creates all sorts of headaches. Learning to use a [linter](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html) like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) or [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) will help by catching bugs like this before they become headaches. [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) is great too, it takes a little more work to setup to get it running but it is much more customizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error! The style of if statements is as follows:

```
if( //conditional statement ){
  // code here
}
```

So yours should be

```
window.setInterval(
  function levelup() {
    if (Xp >= neededXP){
      level = level + 1;
      neededXP = neededXP * 2;
      Xp = 0;
      document.getElementById("level").innerHTML = level
      document.getElementById("neededXP").innerHTML = neededXP
      document.getElementById("Xp").innerHTML = Xp
    }
  }, 10000);
```